# Вопрос о rvalue-ссылке

Tags: c++, c++11

В очередной раз убедился, что мое понимание ссылок C++ оставляет желать... Вот посмотрим простой пример:

```
void DoString(string&& str) { }
. . .
DoString("I'm an rvalue string");
```

Все прекрасно компилируется, как и должно. Теперь попробуем так:

```
string s { "I'm an lvalue string" };
DoString(s);
```

Ошибка компиляции (как и должно быть):

```
error C2664: 'void DoString(std::string &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::string &&'
note: You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

Теперь попробуем сделать чуть сложнее:

```
string&& rs = string("I'm an rvalue string");
DoString(rs);
```

Та же самая ошибка компиляции, что и выше! *Не могу сконвертировать аргумент из `std::string` в `std::string &&` блаблабла*. Но ведь `rs` - это rvalue. И если навести на нее курсор, студия показывает тип `std::string &&`. Откуда вылезло lvalue?

Была мысль, что это потому, что `rs` - ссылка на x-value, а не на pr-value. Однако функция `std::move` тоже возвращает ссылку на x-value, но при этом вызов

```
DoString(std::move(s));
```

прекрасно компилируется.

Так что вопросы у меня появились такие:

1) Что происходит при присваивании `string&& rs = string("I'm an rvalue string");`?

2) Что такое `rs` и каким образом в виде аргумента функции она превращается в lvalue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо вас вводит в заблуждения терминолигия С++. Дело в том, что термин `rvalue` может использоваться для обозначения двух разных, независимых понятий:

- *тип rvalue reference*, тип переменной `str`, объявленной как `string && str` в вашем примере
- *категория выражения rvalue*, результат `std::move(s)` (xvalue) или `string("I'm an rvalue string")` (prvalue) в вашем примере

Так вот, чтобы выражение подходило под тип *rvalue reference* оно должно иметь категорию *rvalue*, а не тип *rvalue reference*. В записи `DoString(rs);` тип `rs` будет *rvalue reference*, а категория выражения - нет.

Comment: Все понятно, спасибо.

Comment: *"чтобы выражение подходило под тип rvalue reference оно должно иметь категорию rvalue, а не тип rvalue reference"* Кстати, еще деталь: ЕМНИП, выражения (в отличие от переменных) никогда не могут иметь ссылочные типы.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, что-то Вы непонятное написали. Одно без другого не существует и то, и то может иметь как ссылочный тип, так и обычный.

Comment: @VTT, я понимаю, что Вы имели в виду, но _«тип rs будет rvalue reference, а категория выражения - нет.»_ не имеет смысла, т.к. там нет никакого типа `rs`, есть только тип выражения.

Comment: @ixSci Я опирался на [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242295/2752075), и цитату оттдуа: [`[expr.type]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1): *"If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis."* Я чуть не так выразился, но суть такая же.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, штука в том, что этот пункт совершенно ни о чём не говорит, что и показано в приведённом Вами ответе. Т.е формально, да, сначала `&` отбрасывается, но никакие конструкции языка этого отбрасывания не видят, потому что всё, с чем работают остальные конструкции это категория выражения. Исключением является только `decltype`, но у него просто свои правила.

Answer (score 1):

> Теперь попробуем сделать чуть сложнее:
>
> ```
> string&& rs = string("I'm an rvalue string");
> DoString(rs);
> ```
>
> Та же самая ошибка компиляции, что и выше! Не могу сконвертировать аргумент из `std::string` в `std::string` && блаблабла.

Разница между lvalue-ссылками и rvalue-ссылками в том, какими выражениями их можно инициализировать.

Сами ссылки (обоих видов) всегда считаются lvalue.

Поэтому нам, например, нужен `std::forward` для универсальных ссылок.

---

> Что происходит при присваивании `string&& rs = string("I'm an rvalue string");`

Создается временный безымянный объект типа `string`. В обычных условиях он был бы тут же разрушен, но так как вы инициализировали им ссылку, для него происходит продление времени жизни ([lifetime extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime)). Он будет разрушен вместе со ссылкой.

(Если я правильно помню, временный объект создается как prvalue, а затем за счет [temporary meterialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) превращается в xvalue. И то, и другое - это подкатегории rvalue.)

Comment: Ну, положим, `std::forward` нам нужен не поэтому.

Comment: @freim Можете пояснить вашу точку зрения? Скажу подробнее: Универсальные ссылки либо превращаются в lvalue ссылки, либо остаются rvalue ссылками, в зависимости от того, чем их инициализировали. Но при этом сами ссылки обоих видов, если их использовать в выражениях, являются lvalue. `std::forward` превращает универсальную ссылку в обратно в rvalue в том случае, если ее изначально инициализировали rvalue-выражением. Если ее инициализировали lvalue, `std::forward` ничего не делает. Таким образом, если бы в выражениях rvalue-ссылки сами являлись rvalue, в `std::forward` не было бы необходимости.

Comment: Вообще-то `std::forward` кое-что делает даже если ей передали lvalue. Но это неважно. Я думаю, вы выразились не совсем точно, но если мы начнем это обсуждать, то это сразу выродится в бесконечное пережевывание тонкостей терминологии. Лучше уж не начинать.

Comment: @freim И что же она делает? *"если мы начнем это обсуждать, то это сразу выродится в бесконечное пережевывание тонкостей терминологии"* Я - только за. :) А то вы мне говорите, что я не прав, а почему - не объясняете.

Comment: "*Если ее инициализировали lvalue, std::forward ничего не делает*" - насколько я помню, она выполняет приведение в любом случае. Просто результат получается разный. "*Я - только за*" - а смысл? По теме именно передаваемых ссылок я вряд ли что-то новое узнаю и вряд ли смогу вам что-то новое сообщить. Пустая потеря времени, я лучше поработаю.

Comment: *"она выполняет приведение"* Приведение lvalue к... lvalue? По идее, она будет приводить выражение к его же типу.

Comment: "*Приведение lvalue к... lvalue?*" - и что вам здесь кажется ненормальным? Приведение rvalue к rvalue вас же не смущает. (в чат уже гонят, пора заканчивать беседу).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86720/discussion-between-holyblackcat-and-freim).

Answer (score 0):

rs - это lvalue, вы же сохранили строку в переменной. Смотрите определения тут http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#1