# Почему вызывается copy вместо move?

Tags: c++, ссылки, copy, move

Есть класс

```
class ArgClass {
public:
    ArgClass();
    ArgClass( const ArgClass& o );
    ArgClass& operator=( const ArgClass& o );
    ArgClass( ArgClass&& o );
    ArgClass& operator=( ArgClass&& o );
    ~ArgClass();
};
```

Шаблонная функция:

```
template< typename Type >
void wrapper( Type&& param )
{
    ArgClass tmp;
    tmp = param;
}
```

Почему данный код:

```
int main()
{
    ArgClass ac;
    wrapper( ArgClass() );
}
```

вызовет конструктор копирования в строке "tmp = param". Параметр функции wrapper имеет тип ArgClass&&, и должен вызываться move конструктор копирования.

Comment: Хм.. Действительно: https://ideone.com/NV5cdz. Кстати, шаблонная функция не при чём: https://ideone.com/8P0an7. И ещё упростил: https://ideone.com/aMMsoh

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вопрос о rvalue-ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916317/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%be-rvalue-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что `param` внутри `wrapper` является локальной переменной, а значит, имеет имя, адрес... - словом, является lvalue.

Чтобы он рассматривался при передаче в функцию rvalue как rvalue, нужно использовать прямую передачу (perfect forwarding) `forward`:

```
tmp = std::forward<Type>(param);
```

Comment: forward я использовал, и видел что в этом случае работает move конструктор. А вот "является локальной переменной, а значит, имеет имя, адрес... - словом, является lvalue." - это не пришло мне в голову.

Comment: Почему тогда

std::cout << "param is a " << ( std::is_const< typename std::remove_reference< Type >::type >::value ? "const " : "" ) << ( std::is_lvalue_reference< Type >::value ? "lvalue" : "rvalue" ) << " reference " << std::endl;

скажет о том, что "param is a rvalue reference"

Comment: По той же причинне, по которой при замене `is_lvalue_reference< Type >::value ? "lvalue" : "rvalue"` на `std::is_rvalue_reference< Type >::value ? "rvalue" : "lvalue"` скажет, что это lvalue. Потому что это ни то, ни другое.

Comment: @Harry, а тогда что это?

Comment: @Владимир любой параметр функции в теле функции является lvalue reference. Для подробностей читайте Скотта Мейерса

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, пусть меня поправят гуру в стандартах, но я понимаю это так, что аргумент может быть чем угодно - и l, и r (да их там сейчас вообще штук 5 :)). Для того и передается как универсальная ссылка - `Type&&`. И поэтому эти свойства типов дают `false`. Еще раз - это чисто мое восприятие проблемы, без ссылки на стандарт.

Answer (score 2):

https://habr.com/post/226229/

В строке `tmp = param` вызовется оператор присваивания, почему конструктор копии?

При явном вызове `tmp = param;` будет вызван оператор lvalue =, потому что он существует и определен, это гарантирует сохранность переданного объекта вне зависимости от того, как именно он принимается в функцию, как lvalue или rvalue.
можно его удалить `ArgClass& operator=( const ArgClass& o ) = delete;` и убедиться, что компилятор пытается вызвать lvalue=

```
class ArgClass {
public:
    ArgClass() { std::cout << "base cons" << std::endl; };
    ArgClass( const ArgClass& o ) { std::cout << "lv cons" << std::endl; }; ;
    ArgClass& operator=( const ArgClass& o ) { std::cout << "lv assign" << std::endl; return *this;};;
    ArgClass( ArgClass&& o ) { std::cout << "rv cons" << std::endl; };;
    ArgClass& operator=( ArgClass&& o ) { std::cout << "rv ass" << std::endl; return *this;};;
    ~ArgClass() { std::cout << "destr" << std::endl; };;
};

template< typename Type >
void wrapper( ArgClass&& param )
{
    ArgClass tmp;
    tmp = (param);
}

int main()
{
    wrapper<ArgClass>( ArgClass() );

    system("pause");
}

base cons
base cons
lv assign
destr
destr
```

При явном вызове перемещения, будет вызван соответственно оператор rvalue=

```
template< typename Type >
void wrapper( ArgClass&& param )
{
    ArgClass tmp;
    tmp = std::move(param);
}

base cons
base cons
rv ass
destr
destr
```

Для конструктора копии:

```
template< typename Type >
void wrapper( ArgClass&& param )
{
    ArgClass tmp(param);
}

base cons
lv cons
destr
destr
```

И перемещения:

```
template< typename Type >
void wrapper( ArgClass&& param )
{
    ArgClass tmp(std::move(param));
}

base cons
rv cons
destr
destr
```

Такое поведение возможно обусловлено тем, что мув разрушает объект и именно явный вызов мув говорит о том, что объект будет утерян, в то время как обычные вызовы гарантируют сохранность объекта

P.S. мувнуть объект можно и по обычной ссылке

```
template< typename Type >
void wrapper( ArgClass& param )
{
    ArgClass tmp(std::move(param));
}

base cons
rv cons
destr
destr
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш ответ прост и понятен, учитывая комментарий пользователя: Ladence "любой параметр функции в теле функции является lvalue reference. Для подробностей читайте Скотта Мейерса " - все становиться на свои места. А конструктор или оператор - это да, я перепутал понятия когда ставил вопрос.

Comment: Только вот правильного **решения** - использовать `forward`, который только при при передаче rvalue превратит `param` в rvalue, в ответе так и нет.

Comment: Намек на это есть в совете использовать std::move - слова "При явном вызове перемещения, будет вызван соответственно оператор rvalue=". То есть если требуется вместо std::move можно использовать std::forward и будет передача по rvalue, в том случае если вам требовалось именно это.

Comment: На самом деле, ваш ответ мне тоже понравился. Он более краткий, и после его прочтения всё встало на свои места. В нём вся суть отражена.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, о каком *конструкторе* вообще вы ведете речь, если у вас в коде вызывается *оператор присваивания*?

Во-вторых, не вдаваясь в формальности: для *именованного* объекта никогда само по себе не будет выполняться move. `param` - это имя. Значит какой-то move исключено, пока вы явно не запросите его через `std::move` или `std::forward`.

В данном контексте язык интересует не тот факт, что `param` имеет тип `ArgClass&&`, а тот факт, что выражение `param` является lvalue. Для lvalue будет вызван копирующий оператор присваивания, а не перемещающий.