# Что конкретно делают std::move и std::forward?

Tags: c++

Я знаком с Move Semantics и Perfect Forwarding. Но меня мучает один вопрос, который заключается в следующем:

```
void function(Type&& argument)
{
    std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(argument)>::value;
    std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(argument)>::value;
    std::move(argument);
}

template <typename Type>
void function(Type&& argument)
{
    std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(argument)>::value;
    std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(argument)>::value;
    std::forward<Type>(argument);
}
```

Если воспользоваться `std::is_lvalue_reference` и `std::is_rvalue_reference`, то станет понятно, что С++ знает, о том, что внутри функций (*lvalue* или *rvalue*). А значит `std::forward` делает следующее: если приходит *rvalue* - он возвращает *rvalue*, если приходит *lvalue* - он возвращает *lvalue*. Т.е. происходит какая-то, на первый взгляд, бессмысленная работа. Однако без `std::forward` "идеальная передача" не работает. А без `std::move` не работает "семантика перемещения". Проверено экспериментально. **Так в чём же всё-таки дело?!**

Comment: как только поймете, что  rvalue и rvalue reference это немного разные вещи, все станет на свои места. К сожалению, в многих объяснениях об этом забывают или просто не говорят. std::move делает rvalue c переданного значения, а не rvalue reference.

Comment: похоже дубликат этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908361/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-move-%d0%b8-forward?rq=1

Comment: @KoVadim, хм, я знаю в чем разница, но как-то не задумывался об этом. Кажется начал немного понимать... =)

Comment: а std::forward стает крут, когда нужно передать несколько переменных. С одной переменной просто - сделал две перегрузки и готово. А если переменных 4? пилить 16 перегрузок?

Comment: *"я знаю в чем разница"* - видимо как раз нет, например `std::is_lvalue_reference` и `std::is_rvalue_reference` не позволяют различать lvalue или rvalue и т.д. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916317/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%be-rvalue-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5/916322#916322

Comment: Кроме того, в приведенном примере `Type&& argument` в первом случае используется для объявления rvalue ссылки, а во втором - универсальной ссылки. Это тоже следует четко различать.

Comment: @KoVadim вообще-то std::move как раз rvalue reference делает...

Comment: нет. если быть суперточным, то std::move возвращает xvalue exression. reference он не может возвращать.

Comment: @KoVadim она возвращает `std::remove_reference_t<T> &&`. Что, по-вашему, означают `&&` в конце?

Comment: о, два амперсанда могут значить много много чего. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move - там как раз написано  "In particular, std::move produces an **xvalue expression** that identifies its argument t.". Да, тип возвращаемого значения rvalue reference, но это не значит, что именно это оно возвращает.  Как я написал выше, понимания разницы между rvalue reference и rvalue (expression) очень важное и ключевое.

Comment: @KoVadim ну, в общем-то, "xvalue expression" - это ж как раз эфмеизм для "rvalue reference". так что написанное вами никак не противоречит тому, что std::move делает rvalue reference

Comment: ключевое слово "expression" (выражение). xvalue, rvalue  - это свойства выражения. А rvalue reference - это просто тип переменной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рассмотрим простой пример

```
template<typename T> 
T&& func(T&& t)
{
    return t;
}
 
int main() 
{ 
    double v1 = 0.9;
    const double v2 = 0.9;
    func(v1);//Ok
    func(v2);//Ok
    func(42);//Ошибка
}
```

Для того, чтобы разобраться что же здесь происходит разберем два правила, работающих в контексте вывода типа.

**Правило первое.**
При выводе типа (в шаблоне или для *auto*) ссылочность типа отбрасывается, т.е., если тип будет выводится из аргумента, то тип будет не ссылочным, за исключением случаев, когда тип выводится совместно с использованием *rvalue-ссылки*, но об этом чуть позже.
Если нужна ссылочность, то при таком шаблоне нужно указывать тип при использовании:

```
template<class T> 
void func(T val) 
{}
//...
double x{};
func(x);//T = double
func(std::move(x));//T = double
func(33.6);//T = double
func<double&>(x);//T = double&
func<double&&>(std::move(x));//T = double&&
func<double&&>(33.8);//T = double&&
```

**Правило второе.**
Ссылки умеют сворачиваться (схлопываться) при выводе типа. Это значит, что если при выводе типа получается *"ссылка на ссылку"*, то она сворачивается. Правила сворачивания приведу как табличку истинности:

```
    &  &&
&   &  &
&&  &  &&
```

т.е. если у нас получается "ссылка на ссылку", то конечным типом всегда будет *lvalue-ссылка*, за исключением случаем, когда получается *rvalue-ссылка* на *rvalue-ссылку*, в таком случае конечным типом будет *rvalue-ссылка*.

Чтобы стало понятнее, посмотрим на примеры с typedef'ами:

```
typedef double& LVR;  //double&
typedef LVR& LLVR;    //double& + & = double&
typedef LVR&& RLVR;   //double& + && = double&
typedef double&& RVR; //double&&
typedef RVR& LRVR;    //double&& + & = double&
typedef RVR&& RRVR;   //double&& + && = double&&
```

Эти два правила при выводе типа позволяют организовать аргументы, которые могут ссылаться на всё что угодно.

Взглянем на первый пример еще раз:

```
template<class T> T&& func(T&& t)
{
    return t;
};
 
int main() {
 
    double v1 = 0.9;
    const double v2 = 0.9;
    func(v1);//1
    func(v2);//2
    func(42);//3
};
```

**Ситуация первая** — `func(v1)`:
`v1` имеет тип `double`.
в параметрах `func` принимает аргумент типа `T&&` (при этом `T` выводится из аргумента). Выражение `v1` будет иметь категорию `lvalue`, значит `v1` не может быть привязан к `double&&`. Однако, если вывести `T` не как `double`, а как `double&`, то мы получаем ситуацию `double& &&`, а значит ссылка будет свёрнута до `double&`. Получается, что тип `T` нужно вывести именно как *lvalue-reference* - *double&* для успеха. В возвращаемом значении у нас `T&&`, а значит при выведенном `T` как `double&` мы получаем `double& &&`, которое также схлопнется до `double&`. Получаем функцию:

```
double& func(double& r)
{
   return r;
}
```

очевидно, что в данной функции всё хорошо и никаких ошибок.

**Во втором случае** — `fucn(v2)`,
`v2` имеет тип `const double`, так что всё будет также, как и с `v1`, за исключением того, что типы будут иметь квалификатор `const`:

```
const double& fun(const double& r)
{
   return r;
}
```

А **третий случай** в нашем коде интереснее — `func(67)`.
`67` — даст временный объект типа `int`, т.е. у нас получается выражение с категорией *rvalue*. *rvalue* может быть привязано к не константной *rvalue-ссылке*, а значит `T` будет выведен как `double`. Для успеха вывода типа `T` можно взять как `double`, и тогда получается код:

```
double&& fun(double&& r)
{
   return r;//lvalue с типом double&& - ошибка
}
```

Так почему же происходит ошибка? А потому, что сама переменная `r` — это *rvalue-reference*, но она — *именованная переменная*, и выражение из её имени (`r`) будет иметь категорию *lvalue*. Как известно, *lvalue* неявно к *rvalue-reference* не преобразуется, поэтому и возникает ошибка при попытке возврата ссылки *r*. А теперь добавим `std::forward` в код:

```
template<class T> T&& func(T&& t)
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);//Добавили std::forward - всё хорошо. 
};
```

Почему исчезла ошибка? Рассмотрим упрощенное устройство `std::forward` и напишем свой простенький аналог.

```
//std::forward
template <class T> constexpr T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept;
template <class T> constexpr T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept;
//Returns: static_cast<T&&>(t).
```

Реализуем свой `forward`, но упрощения ради отбросим `constexpr` и пр.:

```
template <class T>
T&& forward(std::remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept
{
   return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
 
template <class T>
T&& forward(std::remove_reference_t<T>&& t) noexcept
{
   return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

сопоставим это с нашей функцией:

```
template<class T> T&& func(T&& t)
{
    return forward<T>(t);//Тоже всё работает и ошибок нет
}
```

Так в чем же **магия**?
Предположим, что мы вызвали `func` с нашим `v1` — `lvalue`, тогда получаем, что `T` вывелся как `double&`, а значит `t` — это *lvalue-reference*.
Теперь рассмотрим работу `forward<T&>`. Мы инстанцируем его с типом `T` — `double&`.
Значит получаем такой промежуточный код:

```
double& && forward(std::remove_reference_t<double&>& t) noexcept
{
   return static_cast<double& &&>(t);
}
```

`remove_reference_t` уберет ссылку, а в `static_cast` и в возвращаемом значении ссылки свернуться и получится функция:

```
double& forward(double& t) noexcept
{
   return static_cast<double&>(t);
}
```

в итоге, `forward` даст `double&`. Следовательно, передав в `func` *lvalue*, мы получаем:

```
double& func(double& t)
{
    return forward<double&>(t);//lvalue с типом double&
}
```

А вызовем `func` с аргументом (выражением), имеющим категорию `rvalue` (`xvalue`) — например, `std::move(v1)`.
Получаем, что тип `T` в `func` выведется как `double`, а значит мы инстанцируем `forward` с типом `double` (`forward<double>(t)`), при этом передаем в качестве аргумента функции `rvalue-reference`, и получим такой промежуточный код:

```
double&& forward(std::remove_reference_t<double>& t) noexcept
{
   return static_cast<double&&>(t);
}
```

И в итоге вся функция `func` будет безошибочна:

```
double&& func(double&& t)
{
    return forward<double>(t); //xvalue с типом double&&
}
```

В этом коде `forward` уже вернет `double&&` (категория выражения - *xvalue*), а не `double&` (категория выражения - *lvalue*).

То есть, `forward`, в зависимости от аргумента шаблона и аргумента шаблонной функции, на выходе даст либо *rvalue-reference* и всё выражение будет иметь категорию *xvalue*, либо *lvalue-reference* и всё выражение будет иметь категорию *lvalue*. На этом вся магия кончается. Пара простых правил и зелье готово.

Что касается `std::move` - то это просто `static_cast` до *rvalue-ссылки*. Он всегда возвращает *rvalue-reference* и всё выражение имеет категорию *xvalue*.

Comment: "Пара простых правил и зелье готово." Глядя на размеры вашего ответа, чего-то они не кажутся простыми ;)

Comment: @wololo оно чудовищно избыточно. Как говорится - размер не главное. И пока писал, мог что-то еще и напутать. )

Comment: Правила свёртки слегка напутали. Вот здесь об этом подробно https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH3R_16.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp161.aix.doc/language_ref/reference_collapsing.html

Comment: *"А третий случай в нашем коде интереснее — func(67). 67 — даст временный объект типа int, т.е. у нас получается выражение с категорией rvalue. rvalue может быть привязано к не константной rvalue-ссылке, а значит T будет выведен как double."* - закусывать надо

Comment: @user7860670, главное идея понятна: раз есть имя - значит есть адрес, значит lvalue, а шаблон делает каст к нужному типу перед использованием. И тут же становиться понятным, зачем std::forward нужно передавать шаблонный параметр явным образом.